# How do i implement a case when statement in Informatica expression transformation

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to implement the following scenario using expression transformation in Informatica since expression does not support case when how can this be achieved?

```
CASE
WHEN
  (LENGTH(EDW_UPDATE_NOTE) > 500)
  THEN
  'PROC_PWC_MAPPING_NAME ' || TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ||' | '|| SUBSTR(EDW_UPDATE_NOTE, 0, 200)
ELSE
  'PROC_PWC_MAPPING_NAME' || TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') || ' | '|| edw_update_note
END,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIF works like CASE WHEN. You can use -

```
IIF(LENGTH(EDW_UPDATE_NOTE) > 500)
,'PROC_PWC_MAPPING_NAME ' || TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') ||' | 
'|| SUBSTR(EDW_UPDATE_NOTE, 0, 200)
,'PROC_PWC_MAPPING_NAME' || TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') || ' | 
'|| edw_update_note
)
```

Pls refer to the IIF help.

Comment: let me check on the above, thank you for the timely feedback